# PC in VLAN can't ping its own gateway

Tags: firewall, vlan, opnsense

My VLAN's can't ping their own gateway and beyond.

1 - For VLANs to be able to ping their own gateway, do I have to enable the Parent VLAN and assign an IP to it in the OPNsense firewall ?

2 - Do I have to enable DHCP for devices in the VLAN, I know sounds foolish but just checking as all videos I found regarding this on OPNSense show as DHCP enabled which I'm not using.

All rules are allowed on all interfaces, and I'm not using any physical switch, this is a VMware Workstation setup, I have a Windows VM and OPNsense VM.

**Parent VLAN Interface**

[image: Parent VLAN Interface]

**Server VLAN**

[image: Server VLAN]

**Server Ping Failure**

[image: Server Ping Failure]

**tcpdump on em3 shows the following**

```
root@firewallwm:~ # tcpdump -e -n -i em3
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on em3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
18:26:52.651787 00:0c:29:ae:a2:10 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.28.35 tell 192.168.28.47, length 46
18:26:53.316297 00:0c:29:ae:a2:10 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.28.35 tell 192.168.28.47, length 46
18:26:54.316412 00:0c:29:ae:a2:10 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.28.35 tell 192.168.28.47, length 46
```

I checked non device has the MAC address **00:0c:29:ae:a2:10**.

**Firewall Settings**

**[image: VMware Workstation settings]**

**Windows VM**

[image]

Comment: What is your VMware networking configuration for both VMs? Are you expecting the VLAN 30 tag to be added by VMware, or by Windows itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 - For VLANs to be able to ping their own gateway, do I have to enable the Parent VLAN and assign an IP to it in the OPNsense firewall ?

The parent (physical) interface has to be *enabled*, but it does *not* need an IP address just to make child VLANs work.

(It *can* have an IP address configured – its network will then correspond to the "untagged" or "default" VLAN. But if you don't use the untagged VLAN, then the IP address on em3 is not necessary.)

> 2 - Do I have to enable DHCP for devices in the VLAN, I know sounds foolish but just checking as all videos I found regarding this on OPNSense show as DHCP enabled which I'm not using.

No, VLANs do not require DHCP. They act like regular Ethernets – whether you want to use DHCP or not remains your own decision.

---

I would suggest using `tcpdump -e -n -i em3` to check whether any packets from the Windows system arive at all (and whether they have the correct VLAN tag). If they do, then try the same capture on `em3_vlan30` to check whether OPNsense is correctly separating the tagged packets.

Comment: Updated question with tcpdump from em3

Comment: That distinctly seems to lack any VLAN tag. Just a plain untagged packet. What are your VMware settings?

Comment: I could not find how to add VLAN tags in Workstation, its just Host-Only NIC adapter which is added to the firewall and the window VM. I have added Workstation settings to the questions as well.